# How to replace ^M character in perl code in same file

Tags: perl

I am looking to delete control-M character file in perl code (not perl one liner).

I tried this, but it will write to new file. Whats the way to do it in same file?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (IN, '<', "FILE.dat") or die "$!";
open (OUT, '>', "FILE.dat.cpy") or die "$!";
while(<IN>)
{
    $line = $_;
    $line=~ tr/\015//d;
    print OUT "$line";
}
close (IN);
close (OUT);
```

Comment: And you can't just delete `IN` and replace with `OUT` afterwards with renaming?

Comment: You can't do it in one go unless you read the entire contents of the source file into memory first.  You then risk errors if the subsequent write fails.

Comment: How does the perl one liner do it then?
Does it create a temp file somewhere internally?

Comment: Yes it does: `-i specifies that files processed by the <> construct are to be edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening the output file by the original name, and selecting that output file as the default for print() statements.`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Comment: @Alnitak, actually, it could actually be done in-place. Read block, seek back, write block back without the CR. Truncate when done.

Comment: @ikegami true, it's _possible_, but it's not trivial and clearly beyond the OP's capabilities.

Comment: @Alnitak, It's just a question of adding two lines to the code Jens posted. It actually is quite simple.

Comment: What the OP is asking for is clearly not what he wants, because he does not understand what he is asking for. What he really wants is `perl -pi -e'tr/\015//d' file`

Comment: @ikegami you missed two steps - you also have to remember the seek position of the previous read, and seek back to there before you can read the next block.  This is what I meant by "not trivial" ;-)

Comment: @TLP perhaps the OP just wants this as part of a larger program, and needs to emulate the magic that `perl -pi` performs himself without invoking a new copy of perl?

Comment: @Alnitak Then he should go with mpapec's answer. For future reference, he can use `perl -MO=Deparse -pie'tr/\015//d' ` to get the full version of the one-liner.

Comment: Since you're thinking of it as a control-M, you may prefer to write `tr/\cM//d`

Answer (score 1):

store the file internal in a String.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $content = ''
open (IN, '<', "FILE.dat") or die "$!";
while(<IN>)
{
    $line = $_;
    $line=~ tr/\015//d;
    $content .$line
}
close (IN);

open (OUT, '>', "FILE.dat") or die "$!";
print OUT $line;
close (OUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done using `$^I` variable.

```
use autodie;
local $^I = "";
local @ARGV = "FILE.dat";

while (my $line = <>) {
  $line=~ tr/\r//d;

  print $line;
}
```

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eI)

> $^I - The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use undef to disable inplace editing.

So it is `undef` by default, empty string is used to edit in-place, and non-empty string will be added as suffix to backup file name.

Comment: Behind the scenes, it creates a temporary file anyway.

Comment: @choroba is this mentioned somewhere in perldoc? I guess `lsof` shows that.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't be afraid of coping the edited content to a new file, and then renaming.  This is the standard way to edit content unless you're dealing with a file with fixed with records.

Check out [`How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f) to observe most of the ways to edit content, and the majority of them will ultimately be copying to a new file.

My preferred advice is to use in-place edit as demonstrated by mpapec.  The only addition is that Windows forces you to specify a backup, so just need to add the `unlink` line after the processing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'FILE.dat';

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';

while (<>) {
    tr/\r//d;
    print;
}

unlink "$file$^I";
```

If you insist on being able to `open` the file only once, then perhaps you can take a look at [`I still don't get locking. I just want to increment the number in the file. How can I do this?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#I-still-don%27t-get-locking.-I-just-want-to-increment-the-number-in-the-file.-How-can-I-do-this%3f)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Fcntl qw(:seek);

my $file = 'afile.dat';

open my $fh, '+<:raw', $file;
my $data = do {local $/; <$fh>};
seek $fh, SEEK_SET, 0;
truncate $fh, 0;

$data =~ tr/\r//d;

print $fh $data;
close $fh;
```